# What for are the commonly used PKCS-Standards: PKCS#7, PKCS#10 and PKCS#12?

Tags: security, http, cryptography, certificate

What for are the commonly used PKCS-Standards: PKCS#7, PKCS#10 and PKCS#12?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

PKCS#7 lets you sign and encrypt generic data using X.509 certificates. Also PKCS#7 format can be used to store one or more certificates without private keys (private keys can be put as a data payload and encrypted this way).

PKCS#10 defines format for certificate requests.

PKCS#12 provides a container for one or several certificates with private keys.

Answer (score 2):

See on RSA: http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2124.

**UPDATED:** It's funny, that the old URL still on. It's a pity, that it shows **absolutely another content** as more as 5 years before. RSALabs had nice list of all PKCS standards with good overview. The new web-site have a little close information (currently) under [the location](http://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/standards-initiatives/public-key-cryptography-standards.htm) (see [here](http://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/standards-initiatives/section-index.htm), [here](http://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/standards-initiatives/chapter-1-introduction.htm) and so on).

Comment: archive.org links for the above (might be pretty slow): https://web.archive.org/web/20120722014138/http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2124
https://web.archive.org/web/20150924045307/http://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/standards-initiatives/public-key-cryptography-standards.htm
https://web.archive.org/web/20150915180704/http://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/standards-initiatives/section-index.htm
https://web.archive.org/web/20150915155536/http://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/standards-initiatives/chapter-1-introduction.htm